# Can i uninstall python after install anaconda? In Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda

I have a inbox python version with python3.8.10
and i install miniconda with python 3.9.12
if i link `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/bin/python` to `/etc/miniconda3/bin/python`, and do the same things to pip, can i uninstall inbox python?

all things will be fine

Comment: My guess would be that you would be OK, but there is a chance that something uses the explicit path for the built-in installation (`/usr/bin/python3.8`) and it breaks...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming, but instead about OS configuration. Consider [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com) instead.